# Accessing the JavaScript Control for a Kendo UI MVC RadioButtonFor Helper

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I am using KendoUI for MVC.  I created some RadioButtons using the RadioButtonFor helper.  All KendoUI have a javascript controller that manages client-side aspects for each control that you can access.

FOR EXAMPLE: MVC GRID HELPER

```
// MVC HELPER
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SomeDataItem>().Name("SomeGrid") ...other stuff... )

// Grid
var control = $('#SomeGrid')).data('kendoGrid')

...now I can use "control" to set events or do othjer things for the Grid.
```

**I NEED TO:**
I need to setup some events and other things for the RadioButton control client-side.

```
// MVC HELPER
@(Html.Kendo().RadioButtonFor(model => model.Entity.Meter.FlowTypeId)
              .Label("Initial")
              .Value(1))
@(Html.Kendo().RadioButtonFor(model => model.Entity.Meter.FlowTypeId)
              .Label("Reconnect/Resumed")
              .Value(2))
```

**QUESTION:**
How do I access the "Kendo UI Control" for these radio buttons?

**Normal means do not work:**  `$('#Entity_Meter_FlowTypeId_1').data() //<-- empty`

...this would usually give you a list of DATA contents.

Comment: To access the Kendo client-side API you just use `.data('kendo{Control Type}');` where {Control Type} is the type of control. So for a RadioButton it would be `.data('kendoRadioButton');`. But, in your attempt I think the `id` of your control might be wrong - I see no control with an id of `#Entity_Meter_FlowTypeId_1`.... you have 2 controls with an id of `#Entity_Meter_FlowTypeId` it looks like

Comment: You may not have noticed the (now) bolded area on the bottom of the question

Comment: Yes I did read and see that and I was telling you why it didn't work in an attempt to help you isolate your problem. Do you know what the ids of your controls are?

Comment: Can you F12 and select the container of the buttons for a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendo does not have a client-side API for radio buttons.

This is because it is just a radio button with a label, so there are no custom events you can bind to, outside of the vanilla javascript ones. You can bind to these using javascript/jquery, so there is no real point adding these same events to a kendo object.

Setting properties is also limited (text/checked/?), and these can again be easily handled with vanilla JS.

The only other thing you can do is style the radio button, which is described on [the Telerik site](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/styles-and-layout/appearance-styling#customize-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons).

Comment: After so much fiddling...that is what I thought.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As noted, you could use JavaScript/jQuery for this.

To make this a little more concrete for posterity, here is an example tying your Kendo radio button to a click event:

```
$("#Entity_Meter_FlowTypeId").on("click", function () {
    // do something
});
```

Here's an example on how to select (check) said radio button; this will also deselect any other selected options in the radio button group:

```
$("#Entity_Meter_FlowTypeId").prop('checked', true);
```